# fatal: bad revision 'your git UserName'

Tags: git, sublimetext, fatal-error, revision, git-log

when i use sublime text edit a file  and i  wanna to see this file's git log  ,so i use its git

plugin(i had been installed), operate like this: Tools=>Git=>This file=>log,

but i see this error:

```
fatal: bad revision 'Xujiajun(it is my git username)'
```

so i use google to search question to the answer, almost people meet like this "

> git - fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'

"  ,but it is not what i need.

who can help me ?

thanks a lot:)

Comment: You may have better luck creating an issue for the plugin you are using. There are a number of git plugins available for ST. Perhaps you can search on https://sublime.wbond.net/ for the appropriate repository and page to create an issue.

Comment: thanks:)  i had created the [issue] (https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/issues/354) Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Per the issue created on Github, the plugins creator responded and said "Thanks for pointing this out. It was an error in parsing out the commit hash, which I've fixed in [7e400e5](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/commit/7e400e5)."